# Urllib not shown on google analytics

Tags: python, google-analytics, urllib2, urllib

I have script that use Urllib to open webpage in which I installed google analytics.
My question is why if I execute a script there is no visits shown on GA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Analytics script is a JavaScript code and your urllib code does not evaluate it, so this view does not trigger GA.

You can trigger it calling directly the __utm image, but it is not exactly what you want. This way, you have to set all data and send it to GA instead of just trigger some client side code. Check it here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15230/the-simplest-way-to-track-google-analytics-without-javascript

Comment: I edited my answer to add a workaround, but it is not possible the way you want.

Comment: Also note that with the "new" Google Analytics (Universal Analytics) you can do serverside analytics using the measurement protocol (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/).